# Advice for fighting multiple enemies at once

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I really struggle when I have to take on more than 1 or 2 enemies at the same time. For example when training or villages and I have to fight against up to 4 villagers at once using a staff, or when in a tournament and I'm suddenly ganged up on.

My problem is that, even though I can take them down with 2 hits each, when it goes beyond 1 or 2 guys at the same time, they hit me so often that I'm unable to get a successful hit before the next guy hits me and interrupts. And when I try to block I block one hit and then the next one coming is not blocked. It's very annoying and find myself ending up just clicking frantically, which of course just causes stress and not a good fight.

Any advice on skillfully handling multiple enemies at once?

Answer (score 7):

The short version? **Fight them one at a time**.

The longer version: **Stay mobile**. If you stand still like a chump they'll crowd around you and you'll have nowhere to dodge to. Keep moving so that they'll all come from the same direction and get in each other's way enough so that you'll only be facing one of them at a time. Whack them a few times, but be sure to get mobile again before the others catch up. Circle around play tag, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 3):

Increase athletics and wear light armour so you move and attack much faster. Heavy armour is more for cavalry than infantry.

Answer (score 2):

Basically try to turn 4 people attacking you all at once into 4 people attacking you one at a time.  Do this by heading to the outside of the group and keep moving!

My tips:

- As you approach try and make your first hit really count.  Hold an attack position as you approach, attackers will then hold a block until you get close and then go to attack.  As they go to attack strike to the face, hopefully knocking them out in one hit.  An overhead attack or a stab works best.
- Keep stepping back and circling to try and keep your attackers in a line.  This way you are only fighting one at a time.
- Your enemies (and the scenery) will get in each other's way.  If you are facing 2 attackers the one on the right can't attack with forehand swings and the one on the left can't attack with backhand swings.  Use this to your advantage!  In a tournament you can hug a wall or find a corner so that your enemy's attacks are limited.
- Use shield bash and kicks to maintain distance with your attackers and open them up to an attack.
- There is a fairly predictable rhythm to most enemies attacks which you should be able to exploit.
- Having a decent shield to hunker down behind is very helpful when facing multiple attackers.  A shield blocks all attacks whereas your weapon can only block one.
- When you're being mobbed you won't be able to wield a long weapon with much force so either use a short one or, if you don't have a choice like in the training you mention, move more so you are at a distance to effectively use your staff.
- Athletics will make you run faster!  And in some mods heavy armour and equipment will encumber you, slowing you down.